# Architecture of the Triplet Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, triplet-loss

I want to implement face recognition neural network like in [this topic](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/machine-learning-is-fun-part-4-modern-face-recognition-with-deep-learning-c3cffc121d78#.8u44t78xo)(Step 3: Encoding Faces) using dlib library. I already conducted a some research and found out that it's triplet neural network and our goal is to take two images of the first person (`x`, `x+`) and one of the second (`x-`) and find a measurements in which the distance between `x` and `x-` is less than the distance between `x` and `x+`

I also found some simple description of steps which I need to do:

1. First we need a three deep convolutional neural nets (embedding nets) which will extract some features from `x`, `x+` and `x-`.
2. Find distance between `x` and `x-` features and distance between `x` and `x+` features.
3. Take features where distance between `x` and `x+` is less.
4. Use these features for creating measurements.

But unfortunately it's impossible for me to use these abstract things for creating neural network in practice.

**So can someone explain architecture of the Triplet Neural Network by layers?**

Comment: I believe the idea comes from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03832.pdf) and the papers referenced by it.

Comment: there are a couple of questions about it already, for example http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/248511/purpose-of-l2-normalization-for-triplet-network

Comment: The above linked facenet paper is a good example of triplet embeddings, although I don't think it's the first. These architectures are sometimes called "siamese networks." One misconception you have is that you actually only need *one* network, not three. The network is applied to each image in the triplet, so that the weights are shared across all triplets.

Comment: @AlexR. thanks, I already realized that I just need to use batches.